# How could I sort files in bash by numerical values

Tags: bash, sorting

I've got files in the directory and I need to sort them by the version numbers. I try:

```
ls ./bc_containers/ | sort -t '.' -nrk4 -k5 -k6 -k7
```

But the last column does not sort correctly as numerical:

```
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.9.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.8.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.7.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.6.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.5.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.4.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.3.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.2.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.12.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.11.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.10.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.1.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.133.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.132.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.110.16.1.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.110.15.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.110.14.1.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_generalBpmProject_9.8.2.16.xml
```

By --debug I can see problems:

```
ls ./bc_containers/ | sort -t '.' -nrk4 -k5 -k6 -k7 --debug
sort: using ‘en_US.UTF-8’ sorting rules
sort: key 1 is numeric and spans multiple fields
sort: key 2 is numeric and spans multiple fields
sort: key 3 is numeric and spans multiple fields
sort: key 4 is numeric and spans multiple fields
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.9.xml
               ^ no match for key
                                _____
                                  _____
                                      __
___________________________________________
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.8.xml
               ^ no match for key
                                _____
                                  _____
                                      __
___________________________________________
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.7.xml
               ^ no match for key
                                _____
                                  _____
                                      __
...
```

but I don't know how to solve them?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your filenames don't have whitespaces and glob characters as shown in examples, you may be able to use `sort -V` like this:

```sh
printf '%s\n' *.xml | sort -V

com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.110.14.1.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.110.15.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.110.16.1.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.132.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.133.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.1.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.2.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.3.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.4.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.5.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.6.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.7.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.8.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.9.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.10.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.11.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_bpmProject_9.9.134.12.xml
com.aplana.mgc.bpm_generalBpmProject_9.8.2.16.xml
```